# What exactly does cabal install --avoid-reinstalls do?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I've found `--avoid-reinstalls` makes packages build where otherwise cabal fails. What exactly is it doing? Doesn't cabal already try to avoid reinstalls, or shouldn't it?

Comment: should be the behavior by default, and you can modifiy it by the force-reinstalls flag

Comment: It has flags even for default settings, they're probably mostly aimed at external tools that want to be future-proofed against defaults changing.

Comment: @zurgl as I said, adding the flag causes successful builds where cabal fails without, so I don't think it's default behavior. Or were you saying that it *should* be the default but isn't?

Comment: I guess using this flag avoid the reinstall of an existing package, because sometime an exiting package is reinstalled to provide a new version of it, maybe this flag avoid this scenario, this could have the benefit to let the global dependencies safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mailinglist post explains it pretty well: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2011-June/007502.html

> The dependency resolution algorithm will try to make a consistent
>   install plan that allows gitit to be run. However, in order to achieve
>   that, it may decide that it's necessary to reinstall some existing
>   packages in a new configuration (with other dependency or flag
>   settings). Such reinstalls will then overwrite the previous package in
>   the store, and if that previous package was depended on by something
>   else, these other things will break.

The --avoid-reinstalls flag prevents exactly this behavior.